# Display Custom Attribute Multiplace Place on Products Details Page Magento 2

Tags: magento2, custom-attributes, product-page

I'm adding code on attribute.phtml page for call custom attribute on the products details page

```
<div class="product attribute <?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $_className ?>">
<?php 

$upc_code = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('upc_code');
if ($upc_code){
    // Get Value
    $upc_value = $upc_code->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
    // Get Label
    $upc_lable = $upc_code->getStoreLabel();
    echo $upc_lable." : ".$upc_value;
}
?>
</div>
```

> vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/attribute.phtml

but there are issues it's call 3 place

[image]

want to display  under **SKU**

please help me

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

Please Disable the option **'Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront'** into the attribute.Then run the indexer and cache commands

Comment: value display on there but it displays 3 locations want only 1 location under SKU

Comment: Ohk then ovverride the template file and display

Answer (score 1):

You can display custom attributes by creating block after the sku block in `catalog_product_view`

Create catalog_product_view.xml in "app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml"

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="2columns-right" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product_custom_attr" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/custom_attr.phtml" after="-"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <move element="product_custom_attr" destination="product.info.stock.sku" after="-"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Create custom_attr.phtml file in "app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\custom_attr.phtml"

```
<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?>
<div class="product attribute">
<div class="value"><?php echo $_product->getData('upc_code') ?></div>
</div>
```

Comment: ok will try 
can u suggest me what I did the wrong code in attribute files

Comment: you can see in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` file......attribute.phtml file called in three places you mentioned in screenshot.....to display under sku u need to create additional block using xml

Comment: ok, are u know why it displays 3 places when calling in from attribute files if we call it from other files it's ok

Comment: pardon me?.....

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to get this same option to work. I have uploaded the two files with the same code. The UPC # is displaying just below the SKU, however the Word UPC: before the number is not being displayed. I am in need of getting this to work.

I also tried using the same code as the original author used and had the same issue where it displayed the UPC three times in the exact same areas. Need it only once below the SKU.

[image: Sample Image]