# Adding UPC Attribute to Product Page

Tags: magento2, attributes, product-attribute, custom-attributes

I am trying to figure how to add an attribute (UPC) to display just under the SKU on the my product page. I have tried in the past with no such luck. I really need this to work. I have found several different post for this to work and of them worked. The closet one I have found was from this link:

[Display Custom Attribute Multiplace Place on Products Details Page Magento 2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/276179/display-custom-attribute-multiplace-place-on-products-details-page-magento-2)

Problem I am having is the UPC Code from the attribute does display in the right place, however the Label (UPC:) does not show, only the UPC #. I used the same code below:

You can display custom attributes by creating block after the sku block in catalog_product_view

Create catalog_product_view.xml in "app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME\Magento_Catalog\layout\catalog_product_view.xml"

Create custom_attr.phtml file in "app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\custom_attr.phtml"
getProduct(); ?>

getData('upc_code') ?>

[image: Sample Screen Shot]

Comment: Can you share your phtml code, please?

Comment: Not 100% sure what phtml code you need to see, however this is the custom_attr.phtml file that was created per the post I found.

Create custom_attr.phtml file in "app\design\frontend\VENDOR\THEME\Magento_Catalog\templates\product\view\custom_attr.phtml"

<?php $_product = $this->getProduct(); ?><div class="product attribute">
<div class="value"><?php echo $_product->getData('upc_code') ?></div>
</div>

Comment: Replace this `$_product->getData('upc_code')` by `$_product->load($_product->getId())->getUpcCode()`

Comment: Changed the code per your suggestion and nothing changed, stayed the same